# Managing a cart system of customer in an OPENCART

Tags: php, opencart

I am using OPENCART (php) but the problem is that .

In a table `oc_customer` there is column `cart`

When a user is adding an item to a cart the value is updated as `a:1:{s:4:"49::";i:3;}`

What does this codes shows , ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is array:

```
Array( '49::' => 3 )
```

check the [serialize/userialize](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) function:

```
print_r(unserialize('a:1:{s:4:"49::";i:3;}'));
```

Comment: Just to clarify this a bit: a:1 - array of 1 element, s:4 - string of 4 characters, i:3 - integer of 3 digits.

Comment: No. i:3 - integer value 3.

Comment: Damn, sorry, my bad :-)